# FIGMA: How to make auto layout as a gallery view?

Tags: figma

I want to make a webpage with a similar image layout like on this webpage:
https://lyletachikawa.com/

is there a way that i can use the auto layout function in Figma with all the images always going to center, left or right? rather, is there a way to spread them all within the established frame?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "**fill container**" property rather than the fixed width in the Resizing section for the inner object.

Sample Figma Layout

[image]

You can check the sample figma file here: https://www.figma.com/file/Z3vOS8ZWM3749QQnKOCxIo/Auto-Layout-Example?node-id=0%3A1